# Getting only the necessary row

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I am working on a query for a project and sometimes the results have multiple rows for the same entity. What I need to do is:

If the results look like this:

```
   Type        |   Entity
-----------------------------
   TypeA       |      B. Didly

   TypeA       |      J. Hendrix

   TypeC       |      G. VanFleet

   TypeA       |      M. Manson

   TypeB       |      M. Manson

   TypeC       |      M. Manson
```

Then I need to choose TypeB over TypeA or TypeC for M. Manson

My results need to look like this:

```
   Type        |   Entity
-----------------------------
   TypeA       |      B. Didly

   TypeA       |      J. Hendrix

   TypeC       |      G. VanFleet

   TypeB       |      M. Manson
```

I am struggling with using a cursor or finding another option.

Basically if an entity has all three types, I need to only get TypeB for that entity.

There are 10 possible "types" from what I have been told. And the client has given me their ranking of those types. I am thinking a case statement to set the rank.

Comment: Can you ever have more than one A or B or C for the SAME entity?  In other words, if there are multiple rows for the same entity, will those multiple rows always be A and B and C?  What are the _rules_?

Comment: For the correct solution, your question should also define what happens when an entity only has `A` and `C`. Does one of those win? Do you not care?

Comment: I am still waiting on the business side to decide that. The are determining a precedence order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you also only want `B` when an entity has two types, or if they have `A` and `C` you don't care which one you get:

```
;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT type, entity, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
    (
     PARTITION BY entity 
     ORDER BY CASE type WHEN 'B' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
    )
  FROM dbo.tablename
)
SELECT type, entity 
  FROM x 
  WHERE rn = 1;
```

If you care about the order of `A` and `C` in the case where those are the only two (in this example `A` will be returned):

```
     ORDER BY CASE type WHEN 'B' THEN 1 WHEN 'A' THEN 2 ELSE 3 END
```

Comment: I should be getting the final details from the client today. I will give this a try hopefully today and let you know how it goes. Thanks for your input!

Comment: I think this may be the solution. I am sending the results to my users and they will let me know if we are good. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: This solution worked for me. Thanks for the assist! One day, I will just know this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Complete re-edit of my answer based on my deleted comment, "And why does TypeA appear twice in your sample output?"

```
create table testx (type varchar(10), entity varchar(20)) ;

insert into testx (type, entity)
select 'A' , 'Didly' union all
select 'A' , 'Hendrix' union all
select 'C' , 'VanFleet' union all
select 'A' , 'Manson' union all
select 'B' , 'Manson' union all
select 'C' , 'Manson' ;

 select * from
 (
 select a.type, b.entity, b.ent_count,
 row_number() over (partition by b.entity order by b.entity) as rownum
 from testx a
 inner join
    (select entity, count(*) as ent_count 
     from testx 
     group by entity
    ) b
  on a.entity = b.entity
 )y
 where ent_count = 1 or rownum = 3 ;
```

---- Much simpler, this time using count(*) as an analytic function ---

```
 select * from
 (
  select a.type, entity,
 row_number() over (partition by entity order by entity) as rownum,
 count(*) over (partition by entity order by entity) as ent_count
 from testx a
 )x
 where ent_count = 1 or rownum = 3 ;
```

Comment: Thanks! I give this a try and see how it goes. I thought I might have to get row_number involved, but I don't have too much experience with it.

Comment: These both return `C` for `Manson`, not `B` as the OP requires.